# Why does $[L_z,L_{\pm}]\neq 0$ imply $[J^2,L_z]\neq 0$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, angular-momentum, commutator

In a lecture about the angular momentum operator, it is stated that the operator $L_z$ commutes with itself, with $L^2$, with all of spin angular momentum operators, but not with $L_{\pm}$, so;

$$[J^2,L_z]\neq 0$$

With $J^2$ expressing the square of the sum of spin angular momentum and orbital angular momentum, $\textbf{J}=\textbf{L}+\textbf{S}$.

Why does $[L_z,L_{\pm}]\neq 0$ imply $[J^2,L_z]\neq 0$?

$\textbf{Edit:}$

I know that:

$$J^2=(\textbf{L}+\textbf{S})(\textbf{L}+\textbf{S})=L^2+S^2+2\;\textbf{S}\cdot\textbf{L}$$

And I am told that:

$$J^2=L^2+S^2+2L_zS_z+L_+S_-+L_-S_+$$

With this definition of the total angular momentum squared my question is technically answered, but how do they derive this expression? We have, $2 \; \textbf{S}\cdot\textbf{L}=2S_zL_z+2S_yL_y+2S_xL_x$, but how does this translate to the definition stated above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ladder operators are given as $L_{\pm}=L_x\pm iL_y$ and $S_{\pm}=S_x\pm iS_y$, so;

$$L_+S_-=(L_x+iL_y)(S_x-iS_y)=L_xS_x-iL_xS_y+iL_yS_x+L_yS_y$$

$$L_-S_+=(L_x-iL_y)(S_x+iS_y)=L_xS_x+iL_xS_y-iL_yS_x+L_yS_y$$

Combining these, we get;

$$L_+S_-+L_-S_+=2L_xS_x+2L_yS_y$$

Which relates the two expressions after '$\textbf{Edit:}$' that are used to answer the question.